# ¿Cómo Sumar un día a una variable date en Php?

Tags: php, html

poseo una variable Php, con valor Y-M-D, la cual implemento como minimo en un input date, pero necesito a esa fecha mínima, sumarle un día (Ojo un día, no un número más, ejemplo: Si hoy es 31 de marzo, que salga 1 de Abril.

Acá al algunos datos
$fecdess, lo paso por una función, para colocarlo Dia mes año y luego la transformo

```
$fecdess=fecant($var);
$formatFecha = explode('/', $fecdess);
$fecant = $formatFecha[2].'-'.$formatFecha[1].'-'.$formatFecha[0];
```

Comment: No necesitas marear tanto los datos, es mejor crear un objeto `DateTime` a partir de `$fecdess` y luego trabajar con ese objeto. Si me indicas cómo viene ese dato te puedo poner un código de ejemplo, o sea, dime si la fecha viene así: `dd/mm/YYYY` o si viene así: `YYYY/mm/dd` o si viene de otro modo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crear un objeto `DateTime` a partir de una cadena con cualquier formato válido. Luego, puede modificar ese objeto agregándole lo que quieras, días, semanas, horas, meses, años mediante el uso de `DateInterval`.

Por ejemplo:

```
$fecdess="2019/03/31";
$mFecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $fecdess);
$mFecha->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
```

Lo que dice este código es: *créame un objeto `DateTime` usando la cadena `$fecdess` que tiene el formato `Y/m/d`. Luego añade a ese objeto un intervalo de un día (`P1D`)*.

Haciendo esto, `createFromFormat` te evita tener que manipular tú los datos con `explode`. Y, no hay lugar a error, porque PHP trabajará con objetos, no va a tomar un uno para sumarlo al 31, sino que va a agregar un día a esa fecha con toda exactitud.

Aparte de la precisión, la otra ventaja es que luego ese objeto lo puedes reutilizar para presentarlo de las formas que quieras, lo puedes modificar, puedes hacer cálculos con él, crear rangos, etc etc.

Por ejemplo, para presentarlo en diferentes formatos:

```
echo $mFecha->format('d-m-Y').PHP_EOL;
echo $mFecha->format('Y-m-d').PHP_EOL;
echo "Es el día: ".$mFecha->format('z')." del año ".$mFecha->format('Y').PHP_EOL;
```

**Salida:**

```
01-04-2019
2019-04-01
Es el día: 90 del año 2019
```

---

Si la fecha estuviera así:

```
$fecdess="18/03/2019";
```

Puedes crear el objeto, cambiando el formato:

```
$mFecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fecdess);
```

Es decir, `createFromFormat` permite crear un objeto `DateTime` a partir de cualquier dato con formato y valores válidos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudo muchisimo

Answer (score 1):

También tienes la opción de usar las extensiones `DateTime` y `DateInterval` (yo las prefiero sobre el uso de funciones).

Por ejemplo, este código:

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo "hoy    ".$date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
echo "mañana ".$date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

Devolverá:

```
hoy    2019-03-18
mañana 2019-03-
```

Answer (score 0):

Si `$fecdess` es tu variable que contiene la fecha:

```
date(*[formato de fecha]*, strtotime($fecdess. ' + 1 days'))
```

Siendo formato de fecha, un string con el formato de [Date de PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)